# Search within a decimal range

Tags: javascript, logic

```
var a = {28.82:0, 28.91:0, 29.11:0, 30.11:0, 32.22:0, 32.23:0, 32.24:0};

function check(range) // range = 28.90;
if (a[range]){
  // do stuff here... 
}
```

In the above scenario as you can notice, the condition will never hold true. I want to write a logic where it takes into account +/- 0.01 of the range to check inside the array.

I had figured driving all array elements through a range check function but that would be too expensive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no way to use a float that is somewhere in some imaginary range as a key to an objects properties, it's either exactly the key, or not the key. You have to iterate over all the keys and check if they are within your range, and if that's too expensive you have to figure something else out

Comment: You cannot have numeric property names in an Object, in JavaScript. It's okay for the values to be numeric. Still I don't have a clue why you would want every value to be 0.

Comment: these are just some dummy values. actual values would differ.

Comment: You need to make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you do this?

```
var a = {28.82:"a", 28.91:"b", 29.11:"c", 30.11:"d", 32.22:"e", 32.23:"f", 32.24:"g"};

function check(range){
    if (a[range] || a[range+0.01] || a[range-0.01]){
          // do stuff here... 
    }
}
```

Or is that the approach that you were worried would be too expensive?

Note the logical check `if(a[range])` will return false if the value at `a[range]` equals zero or false. If you want the code to run as long as the property exists, no matter its value, you'll need to modify your condition a bit to account for those edge cases.

Edit: As @SaniHuttunen points out in the comments, you can accomplish this with `if(a[range] !== undefined)`

```
function check(range){
    function propExists(key){
        return a[key] !== undefined;
    }
    if (propExists(range) || propExists(range+0.01) || propExists(range-0.01){
        // do stuff here... 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do just `a[key] !== undefined`.

Comment: *facepalm* ...Good call!

Comment: But there is a problem here: Some values cannot be presensented properly with double precision floating points numbers. I.e: `28.83 - 0.01 = 28.819999999999997`. That will fail the test. You still need a tolerance.

Comment: What you could do is `Math.round((range - 0.01)*100)/100` (and `Math.round((range + 0.01)*100)/100`). This will round the value to 2 decimal places efter the subtraction (or addition). This will alleviate arithmetic precision errors. This however might be "too expensive" for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I understand you correctly.
You need to define a tolerance:

```
var a = [28.82, 28.91, 29.11, 30.11, 32.22, 32.23, 32.24];

function check(range) { // range = 28.90;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {  
    if (Math.abs(a[i] - range) <= 0.01) {
      // do stuff here... 
    }
  }
}
```

`a[i] - range` will produce the difference between the value and number you're seeking. `0.01` is the set tolarance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this would require going through the entire object. which would be expensive.

Comment: You keep saying expensive, but do you know javascript operation speeds?

Comment: this is a representative data set. actual data would be much larger and this operation would occur frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Would it help to know which two elements it falls between?

```
var a = [28.82, 28.91, 29.11, 30.11, 32.22, 32.23, 32.24];

function check(arr, range) {
    var match = [];
    arr.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        if ( prev <= range && range <= curr ) { match = [prev, curr]; }
        return curr;
    })
    return match;
}

console.log(check(a, 30.90));
// [30.11, 32.22]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/xn3jx4u3/) demo.